# Test goodness of fit for geometric distribution

Tags: goodness-of-fit, geometric-distribution

Consider a set of variable length non-overlapping intervals on a discrete finite number line.

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  [---]     [-----] [-]     [--------]    [-----]                 [--] [-]     [---]
```

I want to test whether the spacing of these intervals is random. I have two questions.

1. First, is it correct that under a random arrangement the spacing of the intervals should follow a geometric distribution with probability of success equal to $\frac{N}{S}$ where $N$ is the number of intervals and $S$ is the cumulative length of the space unoccupied by the intervals?
2. How could I, using R or Python, perform a goodness-of-fit test for an observed data set?

Comment: The short answer to 1 is no.  Consider the finite-length line $[0,10]$, with two non-overlapping intervals $[0,4]$ and $[5,10]$.  Clearly randomly rearranging them won't give you a geometric distribution for the spacing.

Answer (score 1):

The differences between the "events" have a poisson distribution.  Let $N(l)$ be the number of "events" to occur in $[0,l]$, $l$ fixed.

We know,
$$P\{N(l) = k\} = \frac{e^{-\lambda l}(\lambda l)^k}{k!}, k=0,1,2,...$$
take $0<l_1<l_2<...<l_n<\infty$ where any given difference 
$$N(l_1), N(l_2)-N(l_1), ..., N(l_n)-N(l_{n-1})$$
and 
$$N(l_i) - N(l_{i-1})$$
has a poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda(l_i - l_{i-1})$

Comment: How come it is poisson and not geometric? As far as I understand, the above experiments seems to be repeated bernoulli trials. The time until success of repeated trials is geometrically distributed. The number of successes in a given interval is poisson distributed. So I dont get how you claim that the differences between the events are poisson distributed. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar problem to yours actually, also non-overlapping variable length intervals.

I am right now working on this so I cant give a full answer, also I am not a statistician so I wont even approach this from a math side.

But for your **2nd question**, one possible approach is the following:

1. you compute the interarrival times, so the number of failures between success.
2. In my case I have strong belief that these interarrival times follow a geometric distribution. Hence what you can do is a [probability plot, in python this can be done with scipy.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.probplot.html)
3. I do the probplot with these interarrival times and the distribution i expect them to be
4. If the points lie on a line this is a good argument that they indeed follow this distribution.

Here is an artificial example

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import scipy
from scipy import stats
```

```py
d1 = np.random.geometric(p=0.1, size=50)
scipy.stats.probplot(d1, dist="expon", plot=plt)
plt.show()
```

**Note:** Im using the exponential distribution (which is the continuous counterpart of geometric as far as i understand) because this plot does not seem to work with discrete distributions.

Anyway this produces:

[image]

Unfortunately I cant guarantee that this answer is completely correct since again this is also a new area to me. If I learn more I may update the answer